# Writing data into flume and then to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am using flume 1.5.0.1 and hadoop 2.4.1 trying to put a string into flume and save to HDFS. Flume configuration file is as follows:

```
    agentMe.channels = memory-channel
agentMe.sources = my-source AvroSource
agentMe.sinks = log-sink hdfs-sink

agentMe.sources.AvroSource.channels = memory-channel
agentMe.sources.AvroSource.type = avro
agentMe.sources.AvroSource.bind = 0.0.0.0 # i tried client ip as well
agentMe.sources.AvroSource.port = 41414

agentMe.channels.memory-channel.type = memory
agentMe.channels.memory-channel.capacity = 1000
agentMe.channels.memory-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

agentMe.sources.my-source.type = netcat
agentMe.sources.my-source.bind = 127.0.0.1 #If i use any other IP like the client from where the string is going to come from then i get unable to bind exception.
agentMe.sources.my-source.port = 9876
agentMe.sources.my-source.channels = memory-channel


# Define a sink that outputs to hdfs.
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = memory-channel
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:54310/user/netlog/flume.txt
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.batchSize = 2
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.inUsePrefix = tcptest-
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.inUseSuffix = .txt
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 3
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agentMe.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = /user/name/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
```

I have already put the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374467/unsupportedoperationexception-not-implemented-by-the-distributedfilesystem-file)

```
client.sendDataToFlume("hello world")
```

I see NettyAvroRpcClient not able to connect to the server where flume is running. But am just sending a simple string am i missing anything.

Experts kindly suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration have to be correct otherwise things may not work out. So here is the config to read data into flume and then into HDFS.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks =  k2
a1.channels = c1

a1.channels.c1.type = memory

a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.type = avro
a1.sources.r1.bind = 0.0.0.0
a1.sources.r1.port = 41414
a1.sources.r1.interceptors = a
a1.sources.r1.interceptors.a.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampInterceptor$Builder

a1.sinks.k2.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k2.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.batchSize = 10
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollCount = 10
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollSize = 10
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollInterval = 10
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.path = /user/flume/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k2.channel = c1
```

this should help :)

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you would actually need to set up a Avro RPC source if you want to connect with NettyAvroRpcClient. A sample config would be as follows:

```
# Define an Avro source called AvroSource on SpoolAgent and tell it
# to bind to 0.0.0.0:41414. Connect it to channel MemChannel.
agentMe.sources.AvroSource.channels = MemChannel
agentMe.sources.AvroSource.type = avro
agentMe.sources.AvroSource.bind = 0.0.0.0
agentMe.sources.AvroSource.port = 41414
```

This creates an AvroRPC source on port 41414.

Comment: I updated file with "agentMe.sources = my-source AvroSource" and the above configuration suggested and changed the port of my client to 41414 still i see the same exception. Client says java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused with no clue on server side.

Comment: telnet <hostname> 41414

Comment: repeat that for localhost on the server side. If you can connect on the server but not on the client, check for firewall rules. If you can't connect on the server side, then your process is not running. If that's the case, please provide the command with which you start flume

Comment: On client side i get the exception "Could not connect to the host, on port 41414" and on server side i see "Unable to connect to remote host"

Comment: your process may not be running. check the following things, on the command line: ps -ef | grep java

Comment: if you can't see a prid with flume, then your process is not running. Also check the flume logs for pointers

Comment: can you please suggest for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243745/flume-configuration-to-upload-files-with-same-name