# Flume generated files

Tags: apache, flume

I have a couple of questions

I have flume configuration as note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928225/writing-data-into-flume-and-then-to-hdfs) in answer

1. Flume is generating a file with the name Flume-data.millisecond. Can I assign a custom name? How can I change it?
2. With this configuration I was able to load a 1.5MB file 5 times but when I ran it for the 6th time I got an OutofMemoryError. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Flume is generating a file and Flume-data.millisecond is the name of the file, can i have a custom name? how can i change it?

Yes you can have a custom name as a prefix or suffix to the files being generated.

> > hdfs.filePrefix   : FlumeData :   Name prefixed to files created by Flume in
> >     hdfs directory
>
> ---
>
> > hdfs.fileSuffix  –   Suffix to append to file (eg .avro - NOTE: period is
> >     not automatically added)

Check out the HDFS sink in [flume user guide](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink) for more details.

> With this configuration i was able to load a 1.5MB file 5 times but when i ran it for the 6th time i got an OutofMemoryError. How can i resolve this issue.

You are getting out of memory error because you are using a memory channel with a insufficient capacity. Better using a File channel.

Comment: Why is it better to use file channel as memory is faster i think. Also i tried increasing the capacity to 10000 and transactionCapacity to 5000. Can you suggest what should be the confguration for loading a file of max size 5MB.

Comment: Yes memory channel is indeed faster but prone to out of memory erros in cases of high throughput. Also file channel is more reliable in cases of sink failure as it will back the data up in the file system whereas memory channel would start throwing the data as soon as it reaches the max limit.

Comment: Also i tried increasing the capacity to 10000 and transactionCapacity to 5000. Can you suggest what should be the confguration for loading a file of max size 5MB.

Comment: this depends on the number of events you have in your file. If you look at the documentation, capacity is the max number of events you can hold in memory and transaction capacity is The maximum number of events the channel will take from a source or give to a sink per transaction. Try reducing the transaction capacity and see what is the performance. In my case I have always gone with File channel and it has performed really well. Approx I am transferring 10 million logs per day.

Comment: how can i give the name of the file to be same as the actual file and all its contents to be in same file in HDFS as flume is writing the files in split fashion

Comment: What does it mean "period is not automatically added" ??? I'm trying to use a custom extension on the created files but it is not appended