# Flume configuration to upload files with same name

Tags: flume

I have 10 files with some data varying in length.I would like to store corresponding data in same file and with same filename, but flume is splitting up the data and saving as FlumeData.timestamp. I am using the configuration as below:

```
 a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks =  k2
a1.channels = c1

a1.channels.c1.type = file
a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir = /mnt/flume/checkpoint
a1.channels.c1.dataDirs = /mnt/flume/data
a1.channels.c1.trackerDir = /mnt/flume/track
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 10000000
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 500000000
a1.channels.c1.maxFileSize = 10000000
a1.channels.c1.useDualCheckpoints = true
a1.channels.c1.backupCheckpointDir = /mnt/flume/backup
a1.channels.c1.checkpointInterval = 2000
a1.channels.c1.minimumRequiredSpace = 9000000

a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /usr/local/netlog/
a1.sources.r1.fileHeader = true
a1.sources.r1.bufferMaxLineLength = 500
a1.sources.r1.bufferMaxLines = 10000
a1.sources.r1.batchSize = 100000
#a1.sources.r1.deletePolicy = immediate

a1.sinks.k2.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k2.channel = c1

a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.filePrefix = %{file}
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.batchSize = 100000
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollSize = 10000000
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollCount = 0
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.idleTimeout = 0
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.path = /user/flume

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k2.channel = c1
```

Kindly suggest how i can store same 10 files with same filename and data within it. File size can vary from 2 MB to 15 MB.

The error i see in logs is

```
lib/native org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file conf/flume-conf.properties --name a1
2014-12-03 20:49:47,545 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:61)] Configuration provider starting
2014-12-03 20:49:47,550 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:78)] Configuration provider started
2014-12-03 20:49:47,555 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:126)] Checking file:conf/flume-conf.properties for changes
2014-12-03 20:49:47,555 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:133)] Reloading configuration file:conf/flume-conf.properties
2014-12-03 20:49:47,571 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,571 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1020)] Created context for k2: hdfs.batchSize
2014-12-03 20:49:47,572 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,572 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,572 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,572 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,572 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,573 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,573 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,573 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:930)] Added sinks: k2 Agent: a1
2014-12-03 20:49:47,573 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,573 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,575 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:k2
2014-12-03 20:49:47,576 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid(FlumeConfiguration.java:313)] Starting validation of configuration for agent: a1, initial-configuration: AgentConfiguration[a1]
SOURCES: {r1={ parameters:{bufferMaxLineLength=500, channels=c1, spoolDir=/usr/local/netlog/, bufferMaxLines=10000, fileHeader=true, batchSize=100000, type=spooldir} }}
CHANNELS: {c1={ parameters:{trackerDir=/mnt/flume/track, maxFileSize=10000000, dataDirs=/mnt/flume/data, type=file, transactionCapacity=10000000, capacity=500000000, checkpointDir=/mnt/flume/checkpoint} }}
SINKS: {k2={ parameters:{hdfs.batchSize=100000, hdfs.idleTimeout=0, hdfs.filePrefix=%{file}, hdfs.path=/user/flume, hdfs.writeFormat=Text, hdfs.rollSize=0, hdfs.rollCount=0, channel=c1, hdfs.rollInterval=0, hdfs.fileType=DataStream, type=hdfs} }}

2014-12-03 20:49:47,583 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateChannels(FlumeConfiguration.java:468)] Created channel c1
2014-12-03 20:49:47,593 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSinks(FlumeConfiguration.java:674)] Creating sink: k2 using HDFS
2014-12-03 20:49:47,596 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid(FlumeConfiguration.java:371)] Post validation configuration for a1
AgentConfiguration created without Configuration stubs for which only basic syntactical validation was performed[a1]
SOURCES: {r1={ parameters:{bufferMaxLineLength=500, channels=c1, spoolDir=/usr/local/netlog/, bufferMaxLines=10000, fileHeader=true, batchSize=100000, type=spooldir} }}
CHANNELS: {c1={ parameters:{trackerDir=/mnt/flume/track, maxFileSize=10000000, dataDirs=/mnt/flume/data, type=file, transactionCapacity=10000000, capacity=500000000, checkpointDir=/mnt/flume/checkpoint} }}
SINKS: {k2={ parameters:{hdfs.batchSize=100000, hdfs.idleTimeout=0, hdfs.filePrefix=%{file}, hdfs.path=/user/flume, hdfs.writeFormat=Text, hdfs.rollSize=0, hdfs.rollCount=0, channel=c1, hdfs.rollInterval=0, hdfs.fileType=DataStream, type=hdfs} }}

2014-12-03 20:49:47,597 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:135)] Channels:c1

2014-12-03 20:49:47,597 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:136)] Sinks k2

2014-12-03 20:49:47,597 (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:137)] Sources r1

2014-12-03 20:49:47,597 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:140)] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [a1]
2014-12-03 20:49:47,598 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:150)] Creating channels
2014-12-03 20:49:47,629 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory.create(DefaultChannelFactory.java:40)] Creating instance of channel c1 type file
2014-12-03 20:49:47,635 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:205)] Created channel c1
2014-12-03 20:49:47,636 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:39)] Creating instance of source r1, type spooldir
2014-12-03 20:49:47,654 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:40)] Creating instance of sink: k2, type: hdfs
2014-12-03 20:49:48,108 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.authenticate(HDFSEventSink.java:555)] Hadoop Security enabled: false
2014-12-03 20:49:48,111 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:119)] Channel c1 connected to [r1, k2]
2014-12-03 20:49:48,125 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{r1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:Spool Directory source r1: { spoolDir: /usr/local/netlog/ } }} sinkRunners:{k2=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@1f87c88 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{c1=FileChannel c1 { dataDirs: [/mnt/flume/data] }} }
2014-12-03 20:49:48,130 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:145)] Starting Channel c1
2014-12-03 20:49:48,130 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:259)] Starting FileChannel c1 { dataDirs: [/mnt/flume/data] }...
2014-12-03 20:49:48,147 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.<init>(Log.java:328)] Encryption is not enabled
2014-12-03 20:49:48,149 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:373)] Replay started
2014-12-03 20:49:48,150 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:385)] Found NextFileID 0, from []
2014-12-03 20:49:48,155 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:481)] Failed to initialize Log on [channel=c1]
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:786)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLong(RandomAccessFile.java:819)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.get(EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:417)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:279)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-12-03 20:49:48,160 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:290)] Failed to start the file channel [channel=c1]
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:786)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLong(RandomAccessFile.java:819)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.get(EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:417)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:279)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-12-03 20:49:48,162 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:173)] Starting Sink k2
2014-12-03 20:49:48,163 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:184)] Starting Source r1
2014-12-03 20:49:48,163 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.SpoolDirectorySource.start(SpoolDirectorySource.java:77)] SpoolDirectorySource source starting with directory: /usr/local/netlog/
2014-12-03 20:49:48,185 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.client.avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader.<init>(ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader.java:132)] Initializing ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader with directory=/usr/local/netlog, metaDir=.flumespool, deserializer=LINE
2014-12-03 20:49:48,204 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.client.avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader.<init>(ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader.java:154)] Successfully created and deleted canary file: /usr/local/netlog/flume-spooldir-perm-check-5019906964160509405.canary
2014-12-03 20:49:48,218 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.source.SpoolDirectorySource.start(SpoolDirectorySource.java:110)] SpoolDirectorySource source started
2014-12-03 20:49:48,343 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:119)] Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2014-12-03 20:49:48,343 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:95)] Component type: SOURCE, name: r1 started
2014-12-03 20:49:48,344 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:119)] Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: k2: Successfully registered new MBean.
2014-12-03 20:49:48,347 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:95)] Component type: SINK, name: k2 started
2014-12-03 20:49:48,356 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:143)] Polling sink runner starting
2014-12-03 20:49:48,357 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)] Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed [channel=c1]. Due to java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.createTransaction(FileChannel.java:329)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.getTransaction(BasicChannelSemantics.java:122)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:376)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:786)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLong(RandomAccessFile.java:819)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.get(EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:417)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:279)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
2014-12-03 20:49:48,659 (pool-4-thread-1) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.source.SpoolDirectorySource$SpoolDirectoryRunnable.run(SpoolDirectorySource.java:256)] FATAL: Spool Directory source r1: { spoolDir: /usr/local/netlog/ }: Uncaught exception in SpoolDirectorySource thread. Restart or reconfigure Flume to continue processing.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed [channel=c1]. Due to java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.createTransaction(FileChannel.java:329)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.getTransaction(BasicChannelSemantics.java:122)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.processEventBatch(ChannelProcessor.java:181)
    at org.apache.flume.source.SpoolDirectorySource$SpoolDirectoryRunnable.run(SpoolDirectorySource.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:786)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLong(RandomAccessFile.java:819)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.get(EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:417)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:279)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    ... 7 more
2014-12-03 20:49:53,359 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)] Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed [channel=c1]. Due to java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.createTransaction(FileChannel.java:329)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.getTransaction(BasicChannelSemantics.java:122)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:376)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:786)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLong(RandomAccessFile.java:819)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.get(EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:417)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:279)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Get rid of file channel and use memory channel instead: Failed to "Failed to start the file channel [channel=c1]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, you need a few more props fro hdfs sink:

```
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.filePrefix = [your prefix]
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileSuffix = .[your suffix]
```

suffix would be .tsv or .csv for instance, while prefix can be anything - you can also use variables for date and time - this requires that you use the timestamp interceptor. You can also create your own interceptor and generate your own variables into your file name. If you omit this, flume will add its own sequence between prefix and suffix.

As an addition to our previous comments, the props to disable rollovers are the following:

```
a1.sinks.k2.rollInterval = 0
a1.sinks.k2.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.k2.rollCount = 0
a1.sinks.k2.idleTimeout = 0
```

to access the file name of the original file from your source, append the following in your hdfs sink config:

```
a1.sinks.k2.hdfs.filePrefix = %{file}
```

to simplify your channel config, do the following:

```
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
```

Comment: But how to get the filenames from filesystem and putting into HDFS and how can i prevent flume from splitting my data file. Not splitting the data is very important.

Comment: ahh - if you want to avoid splits, you'll have to disable roll overs. effectively, to quote the flume docs, you'll have to set the following to 0:hdfs.rollInterval, hdfs.rollSize, hdfs.rollCount,hdfs.idleTimeout

Comment: As to the file names: if you want to preserve the file name,  you should reference that file name in a variable in your prefix property. This is possible because of the fileHeader property in your source configuration. You should bear in mind that flume is designed to sort and buffer incoming records, not files, i.e. using flume as a basic copying mechanism to HDFS can be achieved much easily by using a shell script which basically periodically checks your spool directory and does a hadoop fs -copyFromLocal [local file] [hdfs path]

Comment: Updated the original post with latest configuration. I still see "Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown."

Comment: That error pops after the source was shut down - you'll need to check the logs for the first error to troubleshoot. This however has nothing to do with the previous error we discussed as it affects the source, while we were configuring the sinks.

Comment: yes thats correct flume is seeing an error in source configuration what i see in logs has been updated in the post kindly suggest how i can fix it.

Comment: You'll need to provide the text of the error, otherwise I won't be able to help.

Comment: Ok, I would suggest that you also change your channel config, this might be the cause and shouldn't be necessary. see my post for details

Comment: so i should be adding interceptors for my source is that the missing part?

Comment: it speculative, but I believe your problem is more channel based. Did you configure any interceptors?

Comment: No, you don't need any if you don't want to have extra fields in your HDFS filenames other than the original file name

Comment: so if the configuration is fine then why this is not working any suggestions please, added a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 10000
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000000 still no luck, updated the config file

Comment: remove the old log file, restart flume and the paste the entire log file in your post, I'll have a look

Comment: added the complete log, what we are seeing now is a different exception because i added few more attributes to channel, also updated the config

Comment: OK, please observe my comment above. Your source is still using file channel - it should use memory channel instead. If you fix that, everything will work. Your source relies on the channel to work. this is the pointer, btw => Channel closed [channel=c1]. Due to java.io.EOFException

Comment: I prefer using file channel as i will not loose any data. Previously i was using memory channel but now i switched to file. kindly suggest what configuration i can use to make my file channel work.

Comment: OK, if you insist using file channel - which is a lot slower, here's what you need to do: verify that the paths under a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir = /mnt/flume/checkpoint
a1.channels.c1.dataDirs = /mnt/flume/data
a1.channels.c1.trackerDir = /mnt/flume/track are all writable, not on shares (NFS, SMB or what not), not on slow disks etc.. The folders habe to belong to the user that executes the process. The EOFException occurs because flume cannot read from it's checkpoints. If in doubt remove the  1.channels.c1.*Dir properties and use the defaults, which basically create a substructure in home.

Comment: @ErikSchmiegelow By the way, where's the documentation describing variables %{file} and such? I would like to see that. In addition, can I do string manipulation on such variables (like removing the path from the filename) within the Flume agent configuration file? Thanks.

Comment: @menorah84 - the documentation is extremely patchy I'm afraid. Generally speaking, you can reference any header property with he %{header_key} scheme, with the exception of timestamps, which get exploded to their respective Y, M, D and so on props. So if you want to manipulate the path, just set headers accordingly. That you can do using interceptors, see this for guidance: https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/flume-getting-started-with-interceptors/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks much for your help Erik it helped to go close to the problem i found that flume was creating a file in the data source directory .flumespool which i had to delete along with /mnt/flume/* and also rename the data file to the same name as it was if it was changed to .COMPLETED

Comment: Great - happy it worked, it would be nice if you could mark and upvote my answer as well. Cheers, Erik

Comment: but it still uploads data with a *.tmp tags how can i get rid or it?

Comment: The *.tmp files will be cloased by flume once he's done with uploading or a timeout has been reached. If you have old tmp files residing, then that will be from a flume process that hasn't been terminated properly.

Comment: so how can we terminate the flume process correctly so that all the *.tmp files are removed

Comment: Ctrl - C will do, this sends a SIG signal to flume (assuming you're running Linux/Unix). This will flush the files to disk before exit. Killing the process is what you should not do.

Comment: Erik all data from flume is getting written into same file instead of same name of the file. Kindly suggest.