# Unable to load file to Hadoop using flume

Tags: hadoop, flume

Im using flume to move files to hdfs ... while moving file its showing this error.. please help me to solve this issue.

```
15/05/20 15:49:26 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SOURCE, name: r1 started
15/05/20 15:49:26 INFO avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader: Preparing to move file /home/crayondata.com/shanmugapriya/apache-flume-1.5.2-bin/staging/HypeVisitorTest.java to /home/crayondata.com/shanmugapriya/apache-flume-1.5.2-bin/staging/HypeVisitorTest.java.COMPLETED
15/05/20 15:49:26 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
15/05/20 15:49:26 INFO hdfs.HDFSDataStream: Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
15/05/20 15:49:26 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://localhost:9000/sha/HypeVisitorTest.java.1432117166377.tmp
15/05/20 15:49:26 ERROR hdfs.HDFSEventSink: process failed
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:270)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:262)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:718)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.runPrivileged(BucketWriter.java:183)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.access$1700(BucketWriter.java:59)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:715)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/20 15:49:26 ERROR flume.SinkRunner: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:471)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:270)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:262)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:718)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.runPrivileged(BucketWriter.java:183)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.access$1700(BucketWriter.java:59)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:715)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
15/05/20 15:49:26 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: Spooling Directory Source runner has shutdown.
```

Here is my flumeconf.conf file

```
# example.conf: A single-node Flume configuration

# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /home/shanmugapriya/apache-flume-1.5.2-bin/staging
a1.sources.r1.fileHeader = true
a1.sources.r1.maxBackoff = 10000
a1.sources.r1.basenameHeader = true

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/sha
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.idleTimeout = 100
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 100000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.byteCapacity = 0

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

please help to solve this.. TIA...

Comment: Which version of Flume?

Comment: I've seen it is 1.5.2 :)

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374467/unsupportedoperationexception-not-implemented-by-the-distributedfilesystem-file

Answer (score 0):

@Shan Please confirm you have the relevant Hadoop HDFS jars in your classpath for Apache Flume

Also from your sink to HDFS I see that you have port 9000, however the default port is normally 8020, is this correct?